# $J_n(z)=(z/2)^n\frac{1}{\pi(\frac{1}{2})_n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(z\cos\theta)\sin^{2n}\theta d\theta$

Tags: bessel-functions

In "A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions, Watson, p.48" he ends up with this relation for the Bessel function:
$$J_n(z)=\frac{(1/2\cdot z)^n}{\Gamma(n+1/2)\Gamma(1/2)}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n-1/2}\left [ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^mz^{2m}(1-t)^{m-1/2}}{2m!} \right ]dt.$$ How can Ι use this to get this identity for Bessel functions?
$$J_n(z)=(z/2)^n\frac{1}{\pi(\frac{1}{2})_n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(z\cos\theta)\sin^{2n}\theta d\theta$$

Comment: Is it $(2m)!$ or $2\cdot (m!)$?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^m z^{2m} (1 - t)^{m - 1/2} }}{{(2m)!}}}  & = (1 - t)^{ - 1/2} \sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^m (z\sqrt {1 - t} )^{2m} }}{{(2m)!}}} \\ & = (1 - t)^{ - 1/2} \cos (z\sqrt {1 - t} )
\end{align*}
and perform the substitution $t=\sin^2 \theta$, $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. This, together with the definition of the Pochhammer symbol, gives
$$
J_n (z) = \left( {\frac{z}{2}} \right)^n \frac{1}{{\pi \left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)_n }}2\int_0^{\pi /2} {\cos (z\cos \theta )\sin ^{2n} \theta d\theta } .
$$
Finally,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi /2} {\cos (z\cos \theta )\sin ^{2n} \theta d\theta } & = \int_0^{\pi /2} {\cos (z\cos (\pi  - \theta ))\sin ^{2n} (\pi  - \theta )d\theta } 
\\ & = \int_{\pi /2}^\pi  {\cos (z\cos \varphi )\sin ^{2n} \varphi d\varphi } 
\end{align*}
shows that
$$
2\int_0^{\pi /2} {\cos (z\cos \theta )\sin ^{2n} \theta d\theta }  = \int_0^\pi  {\cos (z\cos \theta )\sin ^{2n} \theta d\theta } .
$$